# Do I always have to write a converter for date-formatting?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, format, converters

I often use textboxes in my wpf-projects which are bound to datetime-propertys. I want to format the dates into the german format `dd.MM.yyyy`.
Currently I do this with a self-written converter, which I can give the needed dateformat.

For example like this:

```
<TextBox Name="Date" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type prj:MyBar}}, Path=Date, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}, ConverterParameter=dd.MM.yyyy}" />
```

The only thing the converter does, is to call the `ToString(string formatString)`-method of DateTime.

Is there a 'smarter' way to format a date  with data-binding. The best would be if there is no need to write C#-code. Perhaps there is any existing class in the microsoft-libs, that could do such date-conversion for data-binding, but I did not found it yet.

Would be great if there are any advices,

greetings,
Martin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.NET 3.5 SP1 has StringFormatter.

```
<TextBox Name="Date" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'}"/>
```

Result:
02/02/2010

```
<TextBox Name="Date" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:D}'}"/>
```

Result: Tuesday, February 02, 2010

But result may also vary depending on system default DateTime format.

Comment: Standard Date/Time formatting has been in all the .Net versions, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(VS.71).aspx (version 1.1)

Comment: Is there a possibility to this in .NET 3.0, since I haven't migrated my project to 3.5 yet.

Comment: Just make a string format converter and pass the formatting string as the converter parameter. Then you only need to make one converter for all of them and it's easy to update when/if you do move to 3.5sp1.

Comment: If you're stuck with .Net 3.0 then the only way is to write custom converters. Consider moving to .Net 4.0 when its available and you'll be set =)